# Javascript String from towo points

Tags: javascript, string, replace, char

This is my string:

```
90' Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa
```

I would to get text from two points, so my result will be:

```
Bytovia Bytow
```

Comment: what is a point?

Comment: From ":"     Now i'm trying with indexOf function

Comment: look into: `split()`.  `parts=string.split(":")`  then `leftPart=parts[0].split(" "); rightPart=parts[1].split(" ")`  then `score=leftPart[leftPart.length-1]+":"+rightPart[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "90' Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa";
var output = str.match(/(\d+:\d+)/)[0];
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry if I desturb you. Now I have a problem, because I would to get for example `Bytovia Bytow`. I managed to get only `Bytovia` but not `Bytow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to accomplish this.

Assuming you have only alphanumeric characters between `:` you can use this regex:  `/\w+:\w+/g`.

- `\w` stands for alphanumeric and underscore
- `\w+` implies 1 or more alphanumeric and underscore chars

The implementation will be something like:

```js
const re = /\w+:\w+/g;

const str = "90' Bytovia Bytow 0:0 Skra Czestochowa";

const x = str.match(re);

console.log(x); // prints out ['0:0']
```

If you want a quick way to test your regex, I suggest you use [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)